# how to check number of active user on which app version from fabric

Tags: android, crashlytics, google-fabric

I want to know how much users is using which version of the application from fabric. 
Or is there any way to get the number of users, version basis?

Comment: have no idea about fabric, but you can check that in google play store. Still your question does not relate to Android development, therefore is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

You can check Monthly active users from Answers Metrics.  Active Users means the number of unique app installations across all devices that were active over the trailing 30-day period. For this Foreground activity must happen for a device to be active. For details:  [Answers Metrics](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/answers/answers-metrics.html#monthly-active-users) [How to monitor your app retention in Fabric](https://fabric.io/blog/how-to-monitor-app-retention-in-fabric/)